# How to position text over an image based on the image's origin

Tags: html, css, text, position, overlay

I have an image that's centered on the page like this:

[image]

I want to put paragraph text over each of the image texts. My first thought was to use `position: absolute` and `position: relative`. I used a div to wrap my image and all the text:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <img src="SBDrawing.png" />
    
    <p id="D">D</p>
    <p id="d">d</p>
    <p id="H">H</p>
    <p id="D1">D1</p>
    <p id="D2">D2</p>
    <p id="n-dn">n-dn</p>
    <p id="n1">n1</p>
    <p id="d3">d3</p>
    <p id="DL">DL</p>
    <p id="dl">d1</p>
    <p id="H1">H1</p>
    <p id="h">h</p>
    <p id="b">b</p>
    <p id="Da">Da</p>
</div>
```

And used this CSS:

```
  .content-wrapper{ 
       position: relative;
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
  }
  
  p{
   position: absolute;
  }
 
  #D{
    top:220px;
    left:310px; 
  }
  
  #H{
    top:320px;
    left:180px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);  
  }
  
  #D1{
    top:245px;
    left:260px; 
  }
  
  #D2{
    top:280px;
    left:55px;  
  }
  
  #n-dn{
    top:215px;
    left:80px;  
  }
  
  #n1{
    top:280px;
    left:200px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);  
  }
  
  #D3{
    top:245px;
    left:5px;   
  }
  
  #DL{
    top:255px;
    left:30px;  
  }
  
  #dl{
    top:245px;
    left:260px; 
  }
  
  #H1{
    top:295px;
    left:180px; 
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  
  #h{
    top:35px;
    left:120px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);  
  }
  
  #b{
    top:35px;
    left:185px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  
  #Da{
    top:215px;
    left:330px; 
  }
```

Only the top two styles matter, the rest if for positioning the text. FYI, the `top` and `left` values are supposed to refer to the origin of the image (top left corner of the image).

I imported the photo into Photoshop and used the Info tab to find the coordinates where every paragraph tag should go. I thought everything was fine, but no:

[image]

You can see that some overlap on each other, some are not even close to the image (look at footer). Can someone please find the problem? I'll give you 15 rep! For accepting your answer...

Comment: Open up Photoshop and edit the image to put the stuff exactly where you want.  Will be much easier.

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is because I need to change each label dynamically depending on the query in the URL. Just go with the flow and try to answer my question, cause I need help!

Comment: will the image stay the same but the measurements will change?

Comment: That's exactly what I want.

Comment: @TheJuniorProgrammer look at my answer now, you have tons of errors that you should fix first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - For you to position all of the elements and not have them move out of position, you need the image to not change size.  the `content-wrapper` holding the image cannot use percentages for size since it will resize according to its parent element.  Use a set width and height for the `content-wrapper`.

2 - hard code measurements into the html using the largest measurement that could be displayed.

3 - in your css, add `text-align: right` to the elements holding the measurements.

4 - adjust the `top` and `left` numbers for each element until they are positioned where you want.

5 - remove the hard coded measurement text from the html.

Comment: My image is 381 x 400, and I readjusted my div to 381 x 400. No change.

Answer (score 0):

Holy errors Batman!

this:

```
<p id="dl">d1<p>
```

does not match css

```
     #D1{
    top:245px;
    left:260px; 
  }
```

this:

```
 <p id="d3">d3<p>
```

does not match

```
  #d3{
    top:245px;
    left:5px;
  }
```

Try setting your wrapper to an fixed size currently you have:

```
.content-wrapper{ 
       position: relative;
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
  }
```

Sice all your `<p>` tags are an absolute value of a % it will not work correctly, instead set the `width` and `height` of the div to the same `width` and `height` of your `img` you are overlaying. (in `px`)

Comment: Nope, exact same result.

Comment: Oh that's your problem -jk-

Comment: @TheJuniorProgrammer Also, look at you ID's some do not match your CSS for instance `id="d3"` is not `#D3` in your css. After you de-bug those it should work. Your CSS is case sensitive!

Comment: I did make the d3 error, but the other id is not d1, but it's dl, and I have a css styling for dl. When typing, I thought L was 1, big fail...Thanks for catching it!